# Unable to install OpenJDK 7 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, java, openjdk

Unable to install openJDK 7 in Ubuntu machine.

getting error like below :

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
openjdk-7-jre : Depends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: From where you got this package? What is the output of `apt-cache policy openjdk-7-jre` ?

Comment: I am not  haveing openJDK 7 package and zip file I am trying to find the file. May I know what could be the approach to install openJDK 7.

Comment: In the title you mentioned 18.04 but tagged the question with 14.04. Please confirm the release you're using. Also, openjdk-7-jre never made its way to official repositories of 18.04, therefore, please [edit] you question and paste the output of `apt-cache policy openjdk-7-jre` (as N0rbert already mentioned).